# Give a windows handle (Native), how to close the windows using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, pinvoke

Given a handle of a window, how can I close the window by using the window handle?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way is to use PInvoke and do a `SendMessage` with `WM_CLOSE`.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const UInt32 WM_CLOSE          = 0x0010;

void CloseWindow(IntPtr hwnd) {
  SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: This works about half the time for me. What's strange is that there are some Explorer windows that don't close. Instead, Explorer's address bar just goes blank and the window stays open.

Comment: @AndrewRondeau, I know this is a bit old, but, the behavior you describe could potentially be that you're acquiring/closing the wrong handle, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is another way but you could PInvoke the following:

```
                // close the window using API        
            SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Call CloseWindow via P/Invoke:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.closewindow

Or DestroyWindow

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/DestroyWindow.html

Comment: The first link is a P/Invoke declaration for [`CloseWindowStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682047(v=vs.85).aspx), which servers a different purpose.
The caveat re [`DestroyWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx) is that  it only works with windows created by the _same thread_.